# Good way to keep an anchor tag without default url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In our page we have a slew of anchor tags to which we dynamically attach click handlers. In such a case what is the best way to keep an anchor tag in the mark up?

Currently we have

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" >....</a>
```

We need void value for href as some of them may not get attached with click handlers.

Comment: The absolute _best_ thing to put in the href attribute would obviously be a URL which performs the same action the JS event handler does.
Edit: If that's impossible then use #.

Comment: Using # is a problem when someone clicks on it.

Comment: Well you'd have to prevent the default behaviour of the link either by returning false from the event handler or using the `preventDefault()` method of the event object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ommit the href-attribute and when assigning the onclick also set the cursor-style of the elements to "pointer" , otherwise users with JS disabled will be confused when clicking on the elements and nothing happens.

Comment: Comparing an anchor with href and without href, is the cursor:pointer style the only difference? Ommiting href came to my mind, was not sure how it would behave in different browsers.

Comment: I don't see any difference in that special case, you only use the href-attribute to have the special cursor, this can be done using CSS(in fact you don't need to use a `<a/>`-element, it can be any element)

Answer (score 1):

Returning false from a jQuery event handler will prevent the default behavior (and bubbling) *for you*.  There's no need to mess with the `href` attribute (though that won't hurt).

```
$(document).on("click", "a.yourSelector", function(){
    //your code

    return false;
});
```

Or of course jQuery pre 1.7

```
$(document).delegate("a.yourSelector", "click", function(){
    //your code

    return false;
});
```

For more information on cancelling dom events, see [this question (and answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/javascript-event-preventdefault-vs-return-false) and [this link](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/11/story-on-return-false.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/javascript-event-preventdefault-vs-return-false

Answer (score 0):

The simpler code would be like this:

```
<a href='#' class='do-stuff'>Link</a>
```

The "#" sign keeps the html code clean, and readable

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery(".do-stuff").click(function() {
    alert("clicked"); 
    return false; // disables default link action
  });

});
```